# Select nodes with jcabi using the default xmlns namespace

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jcabi

I a started to use [xml.jcabi](http://xml.jcabi.com/) xml library. It looks like a simple library but I am not able to query nodes if xmlns namespace is set.

Here is my xml file:

```
<MyRequestData xmlns='http://www.myaddress.com/myfile.xsd' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <RequestData>
    <startDate>2016-03-25</startDate>
    <endDate>2016-03-25</endDate>
  </RequestData>
</MyRequestData>
```

And my Java code looks like this:

```
XML xmlRequest = new XMLDocument(requestFileIS);
xmlRequest.registerNs("xmlns", "http://www.myaddress.com/myfile.xsd");    
for (XML requestData : xmlAdHocRequest.nodes("//xmlns:RequestData")) 
{
    String startDate = requestData.xpath("startDate/text()").get(0);
}
```

My problem is that `xmlAdHocRequest.nodes("//xmlns:RequestData")` returns zero nodes. If I remove the default namespace from the XML file and (obviously) from NS register than the query works.

I also tried to register the xmlns (default) namespace by setting its prefix to m istead of xmlns:

```
XML xmlAdHocRequest = new XMLDocument(requestFileIS);
xmlRequest.registerNs("m", "http://www.myaddress.com/myfile.xsd");    

for (XML requestData : xmlRequest.nodes("//m:RequestData")) {
    String startDate = requestData.xpath("startDate/text()").get(0);
}
```

When i try to fetch nodes I only got an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid XPath query '//x:RequestData' by org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.errorForDOM3(XPathParser.java:655)
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.Lexer.mapNSTokens(Lexer.java:647)
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Lexer.java:365)
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Lexer.java:98)
    at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:112)
    at org.apache.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:178)
    at org.apache.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:266)
    at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:195)
    at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:281)
    at com.jcabi.xml.XMLDocument.fetch(XMLDocument.java:429)
    at com.jcabi.xml.XMLDocument.nodes(XMLDocument.java:352)
```

My question is: am I doing something wrong or is this some kind of [xml.jcabi](http://xml.jcabi.com/) issue?

Comment: Your error message does not agree with your source code regarding the XPath.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I update the question.  I am trying to hide my project related data.  What you saw in the stack trace, it was just something that sneaked in. I am positive that the code is correct. It seems that the trick with fiction namespace just doesn't work. I have been able to select the nodes by defining xmlRequest.nodes("//*[local-name()='RequestData']"), however this is an awful sollution.

Comment: *I am positive that the code is correct* is inconsistent with your code not working, so you'll have to forgive us if we don't believe you.

Comment: Without a [mcve] to go on, the best we can recommend is that you see the duplicate link.  Good luck.

Comment: Just as a proof i am attaching an image with full source code published here, exception stack trace and xml content.
 http://i65.tinypic.com/2s151rn.png

Answer (score 0):

Define a namespace prefix (`xmlns=` defines a default namespace -- not a namespace prefix) and then use it in your XPaths.

Specifically...

Change

```
xmlRequest.registerNs("xmlns", "http://www.myaddress.com/myfile.xsd");
```

to

```
xmlRequest.registerNs("m", "http://www.myaddress.com/myfile.xsd");
```

Change

```
//xmlns:RequestData
```

to

```
//m:RequestData
```

Comment: Hi @kjhughes. Thanks for feedback. I tried that but i am getting an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid XPath query '//m:RequestData' by org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl

Comment: Show your call to `registerNs` for `m`.

Comment: Hi!  Here is the code snippet:   XML xmlAdHocRequest = new XMLDocument(requestFileIS);
  xmlRequest.registerNs("m", "http://www.myaddress.com/myfile.xsd");    

  for (XML requestData : xmlRequest.nodes("//m:RequestData")) {
   String startDate = requestData.xpath("startDate/text()").get(0);
  }

Comment: The namespace URI that you register via `registerNs()` has to agree with that declared in the XML.  Yours does not.

Comment: Hi @kjhughess. It seems the stackoverflow removed the http :// www from the comment. In code i have the correct address.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I finally got a correct solution to my answer. jaxbi's XMLDocument is immutable. To apply a namespace, you must chain the calls. The call should be done like this: XML xmlAdHocRequest = new XMLDocument(requestFileIS).registerNs("m", "http://www.myaddress.com/myfile.xsd");